# Double curly braces in VueJS app won't show data from Axios fetch

Tags: vue.js, axios

I want to display the data I retrieved from an Axios data fetch in my VueJS app by using the double curly braces notation. Thought this would be straight forward. However, the dot notation for accessing properties of my data object won't work.

Any idea why?

The data object that is assigned to 'usd' in the data property of Vue instance equals:

```
{ "code": "USD", "symbol": "&#36;", "rate": "46,531.5152", "description": "United States Dollar", "rate_float": 46531.5152 }
```

Displaying {{ usd }} and {{ code }} works, when I define them separately. However, when I want to display {{
usd.code }} I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "code", usd is null.

I tried replacing mounted() with other life cycle hooks, but that didn't work. beforeCreate() and create() do display {{ usd.code }} but still throw the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  
  <div id="app">
    
    <p>{{ usd }}</p>
    <p>{{ code }}</p>
    <!--
    <p>{{ usd.code }}</p>
    -->

  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    Vue.createApp({

      data () {
        return {
          usd: null,
          code: null
        }
      },
      mounted () {

        axios
        .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
        .then(response => {
          this.usd = response.data.bpi.USD
          this.code = response.data.bpi.USD.code
        })

      }

    })
    .mount('#app')

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this happens because `usd` is initially `null`. So when the first html render tries to read `usd.code`, it can't because it's not an object. Try the following:

`<p>{{ usd ? usd.code : '' }}</p>`

Comment: That works. No more errors. Thanks. Is the way I set up my data recovery considered OK practice? I have to display many property of my data object. Setting all {{ object.property }} to {{ object ? object.property : '' }} seems an inefficient workflow. I do see this setup suggested in VueJS documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html.

Comment: You could display a block based on whether `data` is an object or null.. That's how I usually do it. In terms of user experience, that tends to be a good practise too, so you don't see a bunch of empty spaces without any kind of placeholder or loading spinner.

Comment: A block as in: a v-if block in the html body? So this problem has to be dealt with with a conditional in any case?

Comment: Come to think of it, maybe mixins can do the trick. They are ran before the non-mixin properties, I believe.

Comment: Yes, I'd say so. If you tell javascript to read a property of null or undefined, you're gonna get an error in any case. So it's unavoidable (and common practise to do it like that)

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @paddotk is correct and must work.

But I would like to hypothetically expand your problem. Imagine data you are fetching from API is larger in volume and requires to be rendered on UI using multiple state objects or arrays. What would you do now? Add `ternary operator` or `if-else` statement on each object and its nested values? Here the above solution would be considered a bad practice.

What you can do is introduce a flag e.g. `isDataFetched` in your state with the default value as `false`. Now when your API gets fetched change its state to `true`.

Now in your markup, add a `v-if` check on the parent element of what you have to render e.g.

```
<div v-if="isDataFetched">
   <p>{{ object.property }}</p>
   <p>{{ object.property }}</p>
   <div v-if="object.property"> // if it can't be check in .then
      <p>{{ object.property.property }}</p>
      <p>{{ object.property.property.property }}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

This will save you the hassle of writing inline conditional code. Though you still need to make sure that your nested properties do exist which you can do where you are fetching the data. If the data is dynamic hence can't be checked in .then statement then make sure to add more v-if statements on parent where you are accessing those properties.

Comment: Thank you, Asad. This is indeed what I ended up doing. @patdotk also mentioned this approach.